# Django model not being created in celery task

Tags: django, python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery, djcelery

I have a periodic celery task which is not creating my model

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=1))
def store_products():
    products = get_products()
    for product in products:
        Product.objects.create(
            name=product['name'],
            description=product['body_html'],
            vendor=product['vendor'],
            rank=product['rank'],
            source=product['source'],
            price=product['variants'][0]['price'],
             product_id=product['id'],
        )
```

My question is what could I be doing wrong

Comment: Are you sure that your celery worker settings are pointing at the same database? How do you know these objects aren't getting created? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I checked the django admin as well as queried my db.

Comment: I think it's a transaction related issue . My struggle is how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Due to low reputation i cannot comment. But this might help -
Since this is a periodic task 'transaction.atomic' or having 'ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE' will only create a problem if you are creating objects in multiple child process via celery.

Not much can be concluded from the info provided, but the problems seems in

```
products = get_products()
```

if you are fetching some data from models without using primary keys in it, it will create a problem.